# Invalid argument on std::cin >>

Tags: c++

I am a new programmer to C++, so please don't rip me, I'm just trying to learn. The error is both produced in the MS Visual Code Studio and Clang++ (the compiler I use)

I have an error that is pointing to 
`>>` to the second set of 
`>>` in
`std::cin >> varname >> "\n";`

I have tried to replace the `>>` with `<<` thinking I had the wrong operator, but I don't have the wrong operation to my knowledge.

````
include <iostream>
int varname;

std::cout << "Input: \n";
std::cin >> varname >> "\n";

std::cout << "This is the input: \n" >> varname >> "\n";```
````

Comment: What do you expect `std::cin >> "\n"` to do, exactly? What is your understanding of how the `>>` operator works here?

Comment: "I have an error" what error? Also, have you included `iostream`? Where's the namespace for `cin`? Finally `>>` is not an argument, it's an operator. Also, `>>"\n"`?

Comment: just remove >> "\n"

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I did include <iostream>, I just forgot to put it in the code snippet

Comment: on the last line, change >> to <<

Comment: @ttemple Just remove that on the std::cin correct?

Comment: yes.  You are essentially trying to assign something to a constant, which you can't do.

Comment: Is there any good reason to downvote this on a new user who is trying to learn C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do `std::cin >> varname >> "\n";`, because you can't do `std::cin >> "\n";`. The `"\n"` is a C-string literal, which is of a type `const char[2]`, which, in above case, decays to `const char*`. You do not have to understand what decaying is, but you have to understand that with `std::cin`, you cannot use to it modify something that's `const`.

Furthermore, the following: `std::cout << "This is the input: \n" >> varname >> "\n";` can't work either. If you want to send multiple elements to `std::cout`, use `<<` everywhere - don't mix them with `>>`.

To summarise:

- `std::cin >> varname >> "\n";` -> `std::cin >> varname;`
- `std::cout << "This is the input: \n" >> varname >> "\n";` -> `std::cout << "This is the input: \n" << varname << "\n"`;

Comment: The mixing of ```<<``` and ```>>``` was unintentional, and was the only line of code that was that way, the rest was correct. I coded this late at night in a car ride so I was very tired, Thank you for clarifying that I didn't need the ```"\n"``` at the end. I now understand why I don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

- Basically **cin** and **cout** are input stream and output stream
  operators respectively.
- **cin** only accepts input variable name, that can be int, char , float, double and etc., and uses >>(extraction operator/ right shift operator)
- **cout** accepts output variable name, that can be any built-in/user-defined operators. And also it accepts string constant
  (which is anything you are writing within double quotes that is
  string constant) like "\n". and it uses << (Insertion operator/ left shift operator).